# In Angular code, After ngFor Iteration data is is displaying in column wise, but wanted the data to be row wise

Tags: html, css

In Angular code, After ngFor Iteration data is is displaying in column wise, but wanted the data to be row wise
[image]

But wanted the marked rectangular data to come one after the other like  below pic

```
    <div  class="padding_bottom_10 padding_top_10"
    *ngFor="let content of element.contents">
      <span class="align-center">{{content.content}}</span>
    </div>
```

That is the angular code in html, which is iterating and displaying the data

[image]

Comment: put <br> line break after <span> tag.

Comment: Use [flex box with directon](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flex-direction)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a span. Use a  paraghraph instead:

```html
    <div  class="padding_bottom_10 padding_top_10"
    *ngFor="let content of element.contents">
      <p class="align-center">{{content.content}}</p>
    </div>
```

Or, use appropriate CSS.